# Set unix attribute in Active Directory using variables

Tags: active-directory

How can I set UID, GID & home directory value relatively, in Active Directory under unix attributes tab?

For example, instead of writing:

- `/home/ann.white`
- `/home/marie.jones`
- `/home/Jessica.Cox`

I want to format like this:

- `/home/%u`

For all 300 user in Active Directory, I tried with %u but it returns user relative identifier (RID), so what is the variable for username & group relative identifier?

Answer (score 1):

`%<givenName>.%<sn>`

http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm <- sorry it's 3rd party, the table is huge and MS doesn't seem to have one available on their website.

Comment: If `ann.white` is their login, you could use userPrincipalName

Comment: instead of `%<userPrincipalName>` i tried with `%<msSFU30Name>`(because userPrincipalName returns LogonName@domainName.com) and it's working fine. now same thing is not working with UID and GID, may be because UID and GID field allow to type only integer value.

Comment: I'm a lot more familiar with Linux than with AD, but this script may help speed things up: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-task-examples/querying-the-active-directory-with-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017